# None of the hosts for the replica set could be contacted

Tags: mongodb, sharding, replicaset

I am having a problem with my sharded cluster.

I setup a new cluster, with 1 router, 2 replica set shards(2 nodes each), and a single 3 cluster config cluster.

I believe I setup everything correctly, created collections, added indexes, but when I go to insert or query data into the collections, I get the error:

```
Error: error: {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "None of the hosts for replica set configReplSet could be contacted.",
    "code" : 71
}
```

configReplSet is my config replica set. It is accessible from the box, I was able to use a mongo shell to log into the primary of the RS.

Any help into what would cause this error would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my sh.status()

```
--- Sharding Status ---
sharding version: {
    "_id" : 1,
    "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
    "currentVersion" : 6,
    "clusterId" : ObjectId("58a761728dfc0e1090b7c592")
}
shards:
    {  "_id" : "rs0",  "host" : "rs0/mdbshard-b1:27017,mdbshard-b1rep:27017" }
    {  "_id" : "rs1",  "host" : "rs1/mdbshard-b2rep:27018,mdbshard-b2:27017" }
active mongoses:
    "3.2.12" : 1
balancer:
    Currently enabled:  yes
    Currently running:  no
    Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
    Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
            No recent migrations
```

and my shard router config file

```
replication:
    localPingThresholdMs: 15

sharding:
    autoSplit: true
    configDB: "configReplSet/mdbcfg-b1:27019,mdbcfg-b2:27019,mdbcfg-b3:27019"
    chunkSize: 64

processManagement:
     fork: true

systemLog:
    destination: file
    path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log"
    logAppend: true
```

Please let me know if you need any other information, I would be happy to provide it.

Comment: Did you check the logs of primary, secondary and mongos processes ? Do you see any error there ?

Comment: the logs look fine, they are actually showing valid connections coming from the router.
`2017-02-18T01:53:21.575Z I NETWORK  [initandlisten] connection accepted from 10.57.157.199:43293 #109 (10 connections now open)

2017-02-18T01:54:21.575Z I NETWORK  [conn107] end connection 10.57.157.199:43272 (9 connections now open)
`

Comment: This did work, thank you!

Comment: @Gondola_Ride You should post that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps [Relevant Error](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23192)